# IndexOutOfRange exception using a matrix

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, indexoutofrangeexception

My program keeps showing an out of index. For example, the variable `arreglo`. Below I want to save matrix specific indexes in an array and then print that array in a textBox.

I'm pretty sure it's a rookie mistake...

**Code**

```
int [] arreglo = new int[77];
int [,] trans = new int [11,7];

int j=0;
int renglon = 0;

var cadena1 = txtBCadena1.Text.Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < trans.Length;)
{
   arreglo[i] = trans[renglon, cadena1[j]]; 
   j++;
   renglon = trans[arreglo[i], cadena1[j]];
   i++;

   if((arreglo[i] == 9) || (arreglo[i] == 8) || (arreglo[i] == 7))
   {
      break;
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("CADENA NO VÁLIDA");
   }

}
txtBCadena1Resp.Text = Convert.ToString(arreglo);
```

Comment: The `i++` inside the `for(i...` loop looks suspicious...

Comment: Hi there! At which line do you have this exception?

Comment: Which line causes the exception and what is the index `i` when the exception occurs? I'm also suspicous of `cadena1`. What is its value?

Comment: The "rookie mistake" is incrementing your loop variable inside the block. Since you have a condition that `i < trans.Length`, which is good, but you increment `i` inside the body of the loop and then try to use the value of `i` in the `arreglo` array. So when `i` is at it's max value based on the `for` condition, and you increment it inside the loop, it becomes larger than the max index of `arreglo`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error out of index on array arreglo (following what you say), the reason is you have an index i >= 77. You have defined an array arreglo  from i = 0 to 76 (77 values).
It seems the error is comming from the lines :

```
  i++;
  if((arreglo[i] == 9) || (arreglo[i] == 8) || (arreglo[i] == 7))
```

Put a "Console.WriteLine(i)" between the two lines to check the value of i is >= 77

I dont know why you do i++, because your loop increase automatically the value of i.